# new to java - how to write compareTo method for sorting

Tags: java, android, sorting

I have been going through some tutorials on how to sort an object based on one if its properties. For example, if we have a class called person which has a property called name, we simply implement Comparable interface and override compareTo.

However, different tutorials show different code which you write inside compareTo, for example here is [one way](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074821/core-java/sort-it-out.html):

```
public int compareTo(Object o) throws ClassCastException {
Date d = (Date)o; // If this doesn't work, ClassCastException is thrown
int yd = year  - d.year;
int md = month - d.month;
int dd = day   - d.day;
if (yd != 0) return yd; 
else if (md != 0) return md; 
else return dd;
```

}

but yet here is [different way](http://www.javacreed.com/sorting-objects-using-comparator/) to write the compareTo method:

```
@Override
 public int compareTo(Student1 o) {
  return Integer.compare(grade, o.grade);
}
```

as a result I am totally confused as to what algorithm or formula is required to write a proper compareTo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on how the interface `Comparable` is implemented.

If in the class you see

```
implements Comparable
```

then the first `compareTo` method is correct.  This was the way to implement `Comparable` through Java 1.4, the last version before *generics* was introduced.  It's implementing the *raw* interface `Comparable` (without any generics).

If in the class you see

```
implements Comparable<Student1>
```

then the second `compareTo` method is correct.  Generics helps in this case by supplying the type of the parameter in the `compareTo` method.

Both are right, but the first one is obsolete and the second one is now favored.

- [`Comparable` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
- [Java generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on what you're comparing. The reason to override `compareTo` is to define a custom ordering for your Object. The contract for `compareTo(Object another)` is that you must return:

> a negative integer if this instance is less than another; a positive integer if this instance is greater than another; 0 if this instance has the same order as another.

So if you have a student and you want to sort by their age, and you have an integer age field, you could just use `Integer.compare(age, another.age)` as shown above. If your requirements are more complicated, you just have to define your logic for what determines the natural ordering of your objects.